# Xamarin Send data via Nfc in IOS is possible?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nfc

I can't understand if is possible to create an app that simulate an Nfc card on your IOS device. (Send data to nfc reader like a Pos)
In Android is possible and ok.. But I have to develop and app in xamarin or xamarin forms and I can't find any information about iOS devices.

If apps like bizum or payment via nfc exist I think that it's possible..
Can anyone share any information or links to study this argument?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for normal developers to make iOS behave like a NFC card, Apple have restricted that hardware capability to themselves.

It is possible for selected partners to add details to the Apple Wallet for it to behave like a NFC card.

e.g. Passkit, Bank cards, etc

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, but now IOS can write tags right? So If I create an App in android (whit Host Card Emulator) that works like a card, and another App in Ios device that only write tags, if I catch the "Write Event" is possible to do something similar at my goal, right?

Comment: Yes, as a normal developer you can make iOS can send data via writing to a real or emulated tag (On an Android phone or other physical reader that does Tag emulation). This is because iOS see it as a normal Tag, the problem comes when you want 2 iOS device to talk to each other.